Bitwarden helm chart issues
I am trying to setup bitwarden in kubernetes using the official provided helm chart https://bitwarden.com/help/self-host-with-helm/
Installation succeeds, and when I access the web it takes me to the login page where I cannot register or create a user.

I tried to put the email here but I am not getting any emails (still not sure if I need to register a user first). my SMTP works fine when testing manually with telnet against my SMTP server which I tried from inside the same pods/nodes.
globalSettings__baseServiceUri__vault=https://your.domain.com
globalSettings__mail__replyToEmail=no_reply@your.domain.com
globalSettings__mail__smtp__host=smtp.office365.com
globalSettings__mail__smtp__port=587
globalSettings__mail__smtp__ssl=false
globalSettings__mail__smtp__username=your_office365_email@yourdomain.com
globalSettings__mail__smtp__password=your_office365_password
globalSettings__mail__smtp__startTls=true

I also tried gmail and still getting the same.
is there any logs I can view to see what is going on ? I checked the logs for all the pods and I do not have any errors.

Seems that I was accessing the wrong pod which is for admin page
